# Missing value and LSD in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to get the LSD value in R after I drop the value with NA in the data frame. But with no missing values in R, I am still not able to get the LSD value. Is there a way that I can get the LSD value?

```
structure(list(Entry_No = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
Rep = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), `Fall Vigor` = c(5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 9), `Fall Biomass` = c(8, 
5, 5, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 7, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 9, 7, 
8, 7, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 6, NA, 7, 8, 6, 
8, 7, 8), FrzDmg = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8), `Spring Vigor` = c(8, 5, 
5, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 7, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 
7, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 6, NA, 7, 8, 6, 8, 
7, 8), `Spring Re-growth` = c(5.43993875562567, 1.77735165749421, 
3.62893796687236, 3.7239363429685, 3.29870551663342, 1.8493017213381, 
3.93952449443564, 3.07002362446445, 4.39465503642184, 1.38189829972876, 
2.62164242839787, 7.28355491190987, 10, 1.83194399336004, 
0.597735814039809, 0.723117529470425, 0.50174852904522, 0.947105022291771, 
6.4138982972208, 4.58926241735981, 4.8332792032045, 4.1021520999641, 
0.637160825533674, 1.59340271403759, 3.78698711702934, 2.25885027606366, 
2.34614608112497, 4.19895795690022, 4.29287106203313, 4.26678420637498, 
1.03815218844927, 0.426981948475102, 0.455614102272011, 1.41296435251033, 
1.60649348574958, 0.0997406460783899, 1.94273032369817, 4.29707834535632, 
1.04538297408743, 3.2926823689784, 1.84085742124066, 4.21825267944138
)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")

`model3<-aov(`FrzDmg`~Entry_No, data=RF)
out3 <- LSD.test(model3,"Entry_No", p.adj="none",console=TRUE)
out3`
```

I get these result without LSD

> MSerror Df     Mean       CV

> 2.519878 70 5.006944 31.70421

These are the value that I got. There was one missing value and I omitted it but I still could not get the LSD value out of it.

Comment: You need far more information if you hope to get answer. Sample code would be very nice.

Comment: `RF<-
   df[!is.na(df$`FrzDmg`), ] model3<-aov(`FrzDmg`~Entry_No, data=RF)
out3 <- LSD.test(model3,"Entry_No", p.adj="none",console=TRUE)
out3` But I could not get any LSD

Comment: That's better but not enough. Can you generated a code with fake data where you reprodce the problem. Sometimes I do that for my stuff and it helps be come up with a solution myself. Furthermore, which package is LSD.test() from?

Comment: I updated the data in the post. Hope it helps. Thanks JAQuent.

Comment: Hello Sonisa, the code that you updated didn't create a data frame that could used. Could you format this in away that we have data.frame RF to work with. The rest of the code can be debugged  more easily. Also you need to tell people where LSD.test() comes from. This is not an function from the base package. Is it from the agricolae package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the little information you have provided it hard to understand what your problem is but I get the following.

```
# Library
library(agricolae)

# Data
RF <- structure(list(Entry_No = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                      8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                                      11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                                "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
               Rep = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
                       4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
                       3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), `Fall Vigor` = c(5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
                                                           5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 
                                                           5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 9), `Fall Biomass` = c(8, 
                                                                                                                               5, 5, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 7, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 9, 7, 
                                                                                                                               8, 7, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 6, NA, 7, 8, 6, 
                                                                                                                               8, 7, 8), FrzDmg = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                                                                                                                                                    7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                                                                                                                                                    9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8), `Spring Vigor` = c(8, 5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         5, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 7, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         7, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 6, NA, 7, 8, 6, 8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         7, 8), `Spring Re-growth` = c(5.43993875562567, 1.77735165749421, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       3.62893796687236, 3.7239363429685, 3.29870551663342, 1.8493017213381, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       3.93952449443564, 3.07002362446445, 4.39465503642184, 1.38189829972876, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       2.62164242839787, 7.28355491190987, 10, 1.83194399336004, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.597735814039809, 0.723117529470425, 0.50174852904522, 0.947105022291771, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       6.4138982972208, 4.58926241735981, 4.8332792032045, 4.1021520999641, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.637160825533674, 1.59340271403759, 3.78698711702934, 2.25885027606366, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       2.34614608112497, 4.19895795690022, 4.29287106203313, 4.26678420637498, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.03815218844927, 0.426981948475102, 0.455614102272011, 1.41296435251033, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.60649348574958, 0.0997406460783899, 1.94273032369817, 4.29707834535632, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.04538297408743, 3.2926823689784, 1.84085742124066, 4.21825267944138
                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
          
RF <- na.omit(RF)
model3 <-aov(`FrzDmg`~Entry_No, data=RF)
out3   <- LSD.test(model3,"Entry_No", p.adj="none",console=TRUE)
```

For that I get this output:

```
out3

    Study: model3 ~ "Entry_No"

LSD t Test for FrzDmg 

Mean Square Error:  0.2844828 

Entry_No,  means and individual ( 95 %) CI

     FrzDmg       std r      LCL      UCL Min Max
1  7.666667 0.5773503 3 7.036857 8.296476   7   8
10 8.500000 0.5773503 4 7.954569 9.045431   8   9
11 7.333333 0.5773503 3 6.703524 7.963143   7   8
12 7.750000 0.5000000 4 7.204569 8.295431   7   8
2  7.750000 0.5000000 4 7.204569 8.295431   7   8
3  8.000000 0.0000000 3 7.370190 8.629810   8   8
4  7.666667 0.5773503 3 7.036857 8.296476   7   8
5  8.000000        NA 1 6.909137 9.090863   8   8
6  8.000000 0.8164966 4 7.454569 8.545431   7   9
7  7.500000 0.5773503 4 6.954569 8.045431   7   8
8  8.250000 0.5000000 4 7.704569 8.795431   8   9
9  8.000000 0.0000000 4 7.454569 8.545431   8   8

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 29
Critical Value of t: 2.04523 

Groups according to probability of means differences and alpha level( 0.05 )

Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.

     FrzDmg groups
10 8.500000      a
8  8.250000     ab
3  8.000000    abc
5  8.000000    abc
6  8.000000    abc
9  8.000000    abc
12 7.750000    abc
2  7.750000    abc
1  7.666667     bc
4  7.666667     bc
7  7.500000     bc
11 7.333333      c
```

If that's not the output you expect, you need to be more specific about it.

Comment: I got that but I am looking for LSD value. I think with unbalanced datasets, I am not able to get the value. as there is NA value in one. I Dropped that and it is still not giving me LSD value behind CV. Hope I answer your question.

Comment: I've added na.omit(RF) if that is the problem. This changes the output since I am not familiar with the LSD test in general maybe you should contact the authors if that's not the solution.

Comment: Thanks, JAQuent for your help.